# Puzzle about poker and a goat

Tags: probability

I am playing poker with three friends and from a well-shuffled deck we have each been dealt five cards. I have a hand consisting of the four kings and the two of hearts. Being a poker wizard I know exactly the probability that I have a winning hand.
But then I suddenly discover that earlier in the day the family's children were playing with the cards and fed six of them to their pet goat (but I don't know which). How does this information change the probability with which I believe my hand will beat my opponents? Why?

Comment: What does "the two of hearts" mean?

Comment: You are a 4k user, so I assume you know the deal. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @barakmanos That's pretty obvious. A poker deck has 52 cards, 13 of each suit, $2,\ldots,10,J,Q,K,A$. Hearts is a suit $\color{red}\heartsuit$, and it's the $2$ of that suit.

Comment: So one of the kings is a red heart, and the non-king card is also a red heart?

Comment: @AlexR My thoughts are of no value unfortunately.

Comment: @barakmanos He has all four kings and the fifth card is $\color{red}{2\heartsuit}$. Yes.

Comment: @AlexR: So you should remove the "Yes" at the end of that comment.

Comment: @LTS That's a shame. Intuitively the probability should rise because chances are some of the aces are missing so we have a probability that a four-of-a-kind can't be beaten at all.

Comment: @AlexR: And BTW, "the two of hearts" is extremely "un-obvious" if that's the actual interpretation of it.

Comment: @AlexR: If you think of taking the bottom six cards and feeding them to the goat, how does anything change?

Comment: @barakmanos 1. I'm not here to dicuss about such gibberish 2. To an english speaker it _is_ obvious.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hmmm... It could increase the chances as well by ripping apart a possible straight flush...

Comment: @RossMillikan You should write up your comment to my deleted answer as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability distribution of the other three hands has not changed. They are still five card hands drawn from the 47 cards you do not hold. Whether the six cards are on the bottom of the pack or in the goat doesn't matter.